# Thermometer calibration at temperatures away from the ice point and the triple point of water

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, metrology

Calibrations of thermometers at 'Ice point' as well as at 'triple point of water' are well known and promoted by standard issuing bureaus. However, I experience difficulty to find a simple and practical method of calibration(uncertainty better than $\pm 0.02 \:\rm K$) at different temperatures (for example $-10\:°\rm C$ or $+70\:°\rm C$). I guess it is more of an engineer's concern, but maybe a physicist can have an input on the topic.

Comment: There may be off-the-shelf temperature instruments or probes that can measure absolute temperatures to better than +/- 0.02 C accuracy, but offhand I'm not aware of them nor have I had any need to use one in all my years of research. Whenever there has been a need for extremely sensitive temperature measurements at the level of hundredths of a degree, what we're normally interested in are in the relative temperatures between two objects in the experiment or between an object and a fixed, nearby set-point than in determining the absolute temperature of an object to high accuracy.

Comment: Depends on what kind of thermometer this is for. But maybe the melting point of gallium at 29.7646 °C? (ITS-90 value)